# Sqlalchemy autoincrement not working while insert new data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Hi I'm new to the sqlalchemy. And I have a table like this.

```
class Block(Base):
    __tablename__ = "block"

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    blocker = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    blocked = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

When I trying to insert new data, it gave me a error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL
> constraint failed: block.id [SQL: INSERT INTO block (id, blocker,
> blocked) VALUES (?, ?, ?)] [parameters: (None, 1, 2)]
> It seems like the autoincrement is not working? Could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this, it's actually works for me:

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

and it's better than you create a `BaseModel` and put `id, created_at` at them

Comment: You don't have to add `index=True` to primary keys, since they're already indexed, at least in most databases

Comment: Yes, I accept it. but in sqlalchemy and other databases, when you prefer a primary key without ForeignKey, automatically it will be `autoincrement`. I think if you use the above id without the index field, your error will fix. maybe the reason of the error is for `nullable=False`